# Calling Interface or abstract class method through its instance

Tags: java, design-patterns

If I have an interface or abstract class `MyClass` and it has a method `getInstance()` so through which (interface or abstract class) I can do the following.

```
MyClass obj=MyClass.getInstance();
```

Comment: Uhmm.. What's the question?

Comment: got it I can access method through Interface :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInstance` seems to be a static method. If it is then you can have static method inside an Abstract class but not inside an Interface. And if your `getInstance` method returns object of class that is derived from `MyClass` then you can do that.

If you are using Java 8 then interfaces can have static methods.

Comment: thanks it is static and i have interface where i declared this method and implement it in another class but still giving me error       here is the implementation     public static ModelClass getInstance
        {
            get
            {

                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ModelClass();
                }

                return instance;

            }
        }

Comment: and here is the interface                        public interface Facade
    {

        Employee GetDataFromModel();
        ModelClass getInstance();

    }

Comment: which java version are u using?if there is a static method inside interface then it is must be 8